# Matrix spanning R$^3$

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-calculus

Why doesn't $(1,-1,1),(1,1,-1),(1,1,1)$ span $R^3$

Let there be any vector $X$ and then we apply the basic thing that i.e for any three scalars $c_1,c_2$ and $c_3$ and $X_1=(1,-1,1)$ $X_2=(1,1,-1)$ , $X_3=(1,1,1)$ and  $X=(x,y,z)$

To span in  $R^3$
we must have 
$$c1X_1 + c_2X_2+C_3X_3=X$$

Making the augmented matrix with this we get
$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&1&1&x\\
      -1&1&1&y\\
      1&-1&1&z
    \end{array}
\right] $$

Reducing to the upper triangular form, it gives me

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&1&1&x\\
      0&2&2&y+x\\
      0&0&2&z+y
    \end{array}
\right] $$

This shows that I am getting unique solution for $c_1,c_2$ and $c_3$  according to the values of $X=(x,y,z)$ but still this doesn't span $R^3$. Why?

Comment: the given three vectors actually span $\Bbb R^3$

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $(1,-1,1)$ and $(1,1,-1)$ are linearly independent, and for any linear combination the two, the sum of the second and third coordinate is $0$, which means $(1,1,1)$ cannot be such a linear combination. Therefore all three are linearly independent. Since we have three linearly independent vectors in $\Bbb R^3$, they must span all of $\Bbb R^3$.

There must be a mistake somewhere. Either you've taken the wrong there vectors, or there's a mistake your answer key.

Comment: So whenever I want to check, should I use the augmented matrix and if the rank of the coefficient matrix comes out to be equal to that of coefficient matrix (consistent solution), would that mean that they satisfy the spanning condition?

Comment: BTW I believe there is a fault in answer key.

Answer (score 0):

Theorem: If $V$ is a finite dim vector space and T is a linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow V$ then $dimV=dim ImT+dim KerT$ 
In your case: $V=\mathbb R^3$ , and $T$ is the matrix you gave.
So it is enough to check $dimKerT$ to see if $T$ spans all $V$.

we write:

a(1,1,1)+b(1,-1,1)+c(1,1,-1)=(0,0,0)

(a+b+c,a-b+c,a+b-c)=(0,0,0)

Now you have only 2 options:

If there is only one solution a=b=c=0 then the matrix spans V
If there is at least one more solution then $dimKerT\geq 1$ hence $dimImT\leq 2$ then the matrix doesn't span V.